# VBA exception messes up OLE picture object behaviour

Tags: vba, excel, ole

We have OLE picture objects on excel sheet. There is some back-end processing (C++/C#) which returns the result and a boolean value. Based on the boolean value we raise exception. The problem is, in case we raise any exception, our Object handling goes for a toss. And we cannot delete the picture objects. What am I doing wrong? Is it some issue with my code or a VBA limitation. The deletion is not by any code, but simple selection of the (live) picture object and excel deletion.

```
   Dim var1 As Variant
   Dim returnVar As Variant
   On Error GoTo CallingTheBackendFn_Error
   returnVar = CallingTheBackendFn(cellText, outputToCell, var1)

   If Not returnVar And (var1 <> "") Then
       On Error GoTo 0
       Err.Raise vbError, "TheFunction", var1
   End If
   Exit Sub

  CallingTheBackendFn_Error:
       Dim errorNum As Long
       Dim errorDescp As String
       errorNum = Err.Number
       errorDescp = Err.Description
       Err.Clear
       On Error GoTo 0
       Err.Raise errorNum, "", errorDescp
   End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code relating to the removal or insertion of picture objects.